# Need one record from table

Tags: mysql

MySQL query:

```
SELECT day, shown, id_partner FROM myTable WHERE day = "2023-05-11" GROUP BY id_partner
```

I get the result:

| day | shown | id_partner |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-05-11 | 1 | 210 |
| 2023-05-11 | 1 | 217 |
| 2023-05-11 | 0 | 203 |

I need to get 1 record.
If all the records "shown" are true, then true.
If at least one entry "shown" is false, then false.

In this example I need result:

| day | shown |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-11 | 0 |

Comment: Group by on day & shown

Comment: In this case, I will get 2 entries. I need one!

Comment: Why not just `SELECT day, MIN(shown) AS shown FROM myTable WHERE day = "2023-05-11"`?

Comment: SELECT day, MIN(shown) AS shown FROM (SELECT day, shown, id_partner FROM myTable WHERE day = "2023-05-11" GROUP BY id_partner) tt

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is getting the smallest *shown* by id_partner :

```
SELECT id_partner, max(day) as 'day', min(shown) as 'shown'
FROM myTable 
WHERE day = "2023-05-11" 
GROUP BY id_partner
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/-kJjHOer)

Comment: But if all the records are true, then I won't get any.

Comment: Then all you need is getting the smallest shown values

Comment: Thanks for the help. I already got the result from Rob